# Windows phone 8 unit test compatibility

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I downloaded Visual studio RC 2 and started a windows phone 8.0 project. Then I created a phone unit test project. Unfortunately I can't reference my original project in the test project because the test project is targeted to windows phone 8.1.

How can I change the target device such that I can unit test my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this Correctly you need to do the following steps:

- You must have at least Visual Studio 2012 Update 2
- Open up your project in  Visual Studio 2012 and add a new project
- Select windows phone test application
- Continue coding in  Visual Studio 2013

I was able to deploy the unit tests to my phone using this method.